# How to Show original color of this icon

Tags: android

**How to change that share icon color to white**

The code is same for all three image buttons, even icons in the resource file have the same color, but the color of share button is different though in the preview it shows white!

I have even tried running on different devices but same result.

[image: See this image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/save_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"       
            android:src="@drawable/ic_get_app_white_24dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/set_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_image_white_24dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/share_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please check drawable All Folder B.coz no issue with xml code.  it's fine.  So check xxhdpi,mdpi etc all drawable

Answer (score 2):

The answer is lying in your drawable file, please check the color of your picture in the drawable file, I think the foreground color of your share button is black, so just reset the image by right click res->click new->click image asset, and get the share icon,then set the foreground color to white, I think this will work!

Comment: drawable files are all fine and all are same